# Enforce parameter casing for functions and classes python

Tags: python, types, type-conversion

I want python to raise an exception if the argument type does not match the parameter type. Function example:

```
def add_integers (a: int, b:int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

What that function will return with different arguments

```
add_integers(1,2) = 3
add_integers(True,2) = 3
add_integers("1",2) = Exception (because it cannot add str and int)
```

I want to make sure that the function does not except an argument of type boolean and ONLY integers. I know I can make an if statement to check the type and raise an exception myself or maybe use a decorator function , but I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: What is wrong with the `TypeError` which is raised?

Comment: It is not raised for booleans in this case, python will handle True as 1, but I want it to give me a TypeError

Comment: My opinion is that you will be better off having a unit test check these things. What advantage do you get with an exception at runtime?

Comment: If you want python to work more like a statically typed language, you should check out [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). Without mypy type hints only serve as code documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) .
This returns the class of the object and does not consider sub-classes. Which is an issue with `isinstance` as it will also return true if you check if a `boolean` is an `int`

```
>>> type(1) is int
True
>>> type(True) is int
False
```